# Why can't I print a string point in C?

Tags: c, printf, scanf, point

Why I run the code and I just got a **segmentation fault**?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *string = "hello,world";
    // printf("0x%p\n",string);
    printf("Command:");
    scanf("%s",string);
    printf("%s",string);
    // printf("0x%p\n",&(""));
    // printf("0x%p\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ![runtime](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/9sauXTPkMb73xz73tss9Ot3Boxk8PTe4n4vMqZsFvoHQSo0d7PWW8HdEe6kcBLLnmv8VzhgECu6i354=w1680-h944-rw)

Comment: String literals can not be changed.

Comment: But it is char*,not a const char*.I just change its location.

Comment: In this case You should have done like `const char *string = "hello,world";`. because The essence of contents can not be changed

Comment: See [c11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **6.4.5 String literals** p7 _It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined._

Comment: But the code like this,and I can run it in the another machine and my own machine in other day.

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined behavior. It includes both. So Don't expect to work as you wish.

Comment: So how should I do to fix the code?

Comment: `char command[64] = "";
printf("Command:");fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%63s", command);
    printf("%s\n", command);`

Comment: but if I want to scan a string but it's length is unknown,how to do?

Comment: If available { (1) `char *s = NULL; scanf("%ms", &s);` (2) Use `getline` } . (3) Extend buffer according to reading by using `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Shall I use %ms?

Comment: It is one of the choices if it is available.  That is the simplest.

Comment: But it doesn't work in my PC

Comment: Then please select (3).

Comment: So I have to set a length for the string?

Comment: It is necessary to manage the size of used memory and the size of secured memory rather than the current length of the string.

Comment: Examples of such processing are many on this site and other sites. one of exapmple, [GetString in cs50.c](https://github.com/CoreData/cs50/blob/master/pset1/cs50.c)